# Confusion about the definition of upper bounds of a set

Tags: terminology

I am confused about upper bounds of a set.

Consider a set:

$A = ${$1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7$}

How many upperbounds are there?

**Does the upperbound need to be in the set?**

Also about supremum. What is the difference between a supremum and an upper bound?

Comment: An `upperbound` is any number greater than or equal to every number in A. Here A has a `greatest element`, 7, so any number $ge$ 7 will be an upperbound for A and, except for 7, it will not be in A. The supremum is the `least` upperbound. It may or may not be it A. If it is in A, it's the greatest element of A.

Answer (score 2):

An upper bound is any number $U$ with the property that $a\leq U$ for each element $a$ of $A$.

For example, $10$ is an upper bound for your $A$ because $1\leq 10$, $2\leq 10$, $3\leq 10$, $4\leq 10$, $5\leq 10$, $6\leq 10$, and $7\leq 10$.

Obviously, if you find one number $U$ that is an upper bound for $A$, then also every number greater than $U$ is also an upper bound. That's because if $V>U$, then $a\leq U$ implies $a\leq V$.

But, among all of the  upper bounds, there will be a smallest upper bound (assuming the set $A$ is not empty). That number is called the *least upper bound* of $A$. The term *supremum* is just another word for *least upper bound*. You will see this written variously as $$\sup A$$ or $$\operatorname{lub} A$$

In your case, the least upper bound is $7$. Any time a set has a maximum, this maximum coincides with the least upper bound. For example, every finite nonempty set has a maximum.

But if the set is infinite, the maximum value might happen to be missing from the set. For example, the set of numbers $$\{0.9, 0.99, 0.999, 0.9999,\cdots\}$$ contains elements that get arbitrarily close to $1$, but $1$ itself is not in the set. $1$ is an upper bound for the set, and it is the least upper bound for the set, but it is not the maximum for the set. Technically, the maximum of a set must belong to that set.